# Clean URL Structure for WooCommerce within a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, url-rewriting

I've got an existing website that I am wanting to attach a wordpress blog and woocommerce shop to. For a lot of reasons, I'd really like to have the wordpress install be within it's own directory in my file structure. I'd really like to have a url structure like this:

```
mywebsite.com/blog
mywebsite.com/store
```

I tried putting wordpress in the /blog directory and adding a rewrite for the store using

```
RewriteRule ^store$ /blog/shop [NC,L,QSA]
```

But that really messes with Wordpress's rewrites. I'd like to do this in a way that keeps Wordpress upgradable.

Comment: For simplicity you could just change the slugs of the blog and shop pages to something other than 'shop' and 'blog'.  Maybe prefix/append them with some text...

Comment: `blog` isn't a slug. It's the actual directory. `shop` is a slug but the URL is `/blog/slug`

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything with rewrites, installing WordPress into a sub directory is a common thing.  After install just refresh the permalinks and it should work.

Comment: It works well, it's just not the URL structure I want. I'd really like the shop to have a url that wasn't preceded by `blog` or anything else.

Comment: I've added an answer for you to check.  I use sub-directory installs all the time and the subdirectory is always excluded in my permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your .htaccess looks like this.  This will create your permalinks without a trailing /blog/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also ensure that in Settings/General you have your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) options setup as `http://mywebsite.com/blog`

Comment: Yea it will work fine, each install has it's own .htaccess file.

Comment: I thought you were saying to put this in the main `.htaccess` file. This is already what my `/blog/.htaccess` looks like. I'm not sure we're both trying to solve the same problem. I appreciate your help. I'm not sure how to clarify what I'm trying to do any more than the initial question states.

Comment: You want the base subdirectory removed form the URL I understand the question.  Check in your settings/general options that you have removed the subdirectory and refresh the permalinks.  You shouldn't need to touch the .htaccess file at all WordPress will handle this when you refresh the permalinks.

Comment: The .htaccess file you shared is the same as the one I already have.